# ERROR in @angular-redux/form/angular-redux-form.ts(3,32): Error during template compile of 'composeReducers'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular9, angular-redux

I have updated the angular app from 8 to 9, after updating when I run the application, it gives me a error as

```
ERROR in @angular-redux/form/angular-redux-form.ts(3,32): Error during template compile of 'composeReducers'
  Function expressions are not supported in decorators
    Consider changing the function expression into an exported function.
```

In the compile section enableIvy as false

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "enableIvy": false
  }
```

Here is the package

```
    "@angular-redux/form": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular-redux/router": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular-redux/store": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.12",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.12",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.12",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.12",
```

Comment: have you tried removing the ```node_modules``` and ```package_lock.json``` and re-installing all dependencies using ```npm install```

Comment: Yes, I did,. Didn't work

Comment: see this : `ERROR in @angular-redux/form/angular-redux-form.ts(3,32)` goto your angular-redux-form.ts line 3 , there is error, fix it. or share us the code so that we can look into it

Comment: btw this should not be a good way, i mean if u have 1000 components u can't go to file and fix each time right? so a better way is create a blank project then create component init one by one and paste ur code into it for each file

Comment: That is from the library, how can I change that the redux library